# Putting a click event for a dialogue box with Django Tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to make a click event with Django Tables2 so that whenever someone clicks on a delete link in a row it will create a dialogue box for confirmation before deleting the row. Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Schedules(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=COURSE_NAME_CHOICES, default='a-plus')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='south_plainfield')
    room = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=ROOM_CHOICES, default='A')
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.date.today)
    start_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=START_TIME_CHOICES, default='eight-thirty am')
    end_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=END_TIME_CHOICES, default='eight-thirty am')
    instructor = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=INSTRUCTOR_CHOICES, default='adewale')
    total_hours = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=TOTAL_HOURS_CHOICES, default='six')
    hours_per_class = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=HOURS_PER_CLASS_CHOICES, default='four_and_half')
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    interval = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=INTERVAL_CHOICES, default='1 day')
    initiated_by = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    schedule_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

tables.py

```
class ScheduleListTable(tables.Table):
    change = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="/schedule/update_schedule/{{ record.id }}">Update</a> / Cancel / Event / '
                                   '<a href="/schedule/delete_schedule/{{ record.id }}" 
                                   onclick="return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")">Delete</a>',
                                   verbose_name=u'Change', )
    class Meta:
        model = Schedules
        fields = ('id', 'course_name', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'hours_per_class', 'instructor', 'change',)
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

views.py

```
def schedule_List(request):
    context_dict = {}
    schedule_list = Schedules.objects.order_by('start_date')
    table = ScheduleListTable(schedule_list)
    context_dict['table'] = table
    return render(request, "schedule/schedule_list.html", context_dict)
```

schedule_list.html

```
<div id="schedule_list_table">
    {% if table %}
        {% render_table table %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

For some reason, I can't make the onclick event that makes the confirmation dialogue box appear, and it just goes straight to deleting. I assume that it's written incorrectly in tables.py, but I don't know how to write it correctly in that case. Or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the rendered html, for example using your browsers inspect context menu option. I think you could see there that there is a problem with the double quotes you use.

The `onclick`-attribute is enclosed by double quotes, but the message passed as argument to `confirm()` is also enclosed by double quotes. This results in your browser interpreting the attribute as `onclick="return confirm(" and ignores the gibberish it cannot understand which is your message.

You can fix that by using single quotes to enclose the message argument to `confirm()`, either by escaping them in the syntax you used (`\'`), or by using triple quotes like this:

```
template_code = '''
<a href="/schedule/update_schedule/{{ record.id }}">Update</a> / Cancel / Event /
<a href="/schedule/delete_schedule/{{ record.id }}" 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">Delete</a>'''
```